# WCF Client: Can asynchronous methods be invoked at the same time?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, wcf-client

I have a WCF service that provides a couple of methods. A Windows Forms client needs to call these methods regularly to update its display.

One method returns the current service status, the other method returns the current server configuration options. The status is obtained every 2 seconds, the configuration is obtained every 10 seconds. I'm using asynchronous calls.

I only have one instance of my WCF client in the application, created at startup and recreated in case communication breaks down. Will it be a problem using the same instance for both calls? Sooner or later both async calls will be invoked "at the same time". Can the client handle this or should I create a separate instance for each "timer"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same `proxy` instance to call both operations on service.